# Built-In Self Test LCD

Tags: lcd, touchscreen, test

I've recently been trying to connect a custom LCD (ET101005DSAK0) to an Embedded System on Module however without any success. When debugging why the LCD is not working I wanted to make use of the BIST (built-in self test) PIN of the LCD.

However, the datasheet of my LCD doesn't give any description of what the BIST pin should output. I did some research by looking at the BIST output of other LCDs for example:

[image: example of BIST pattern]

And even though this is similar to what my LCD is outputting it is not quite the same as can be seen in the GIF of my output below.

[image: Output of LCD]

So in the GIF you can see that the screen is displaying some sort of RGB pattern, which according to other datasheets is indeed a common pattern to display when doing these BIST tests.

However, I would have expected the screen to go from solid red to green and finally blue. What I am seeing is that the colors for some reason are fading inwards. Also, there seems to be this peculiar black line in the middle of the LCD. Since this is a Built-In Self Test (no clock signals or any signals connected apart from the BIST pin and power) I expected to see the full screen display solid colors.

Can anyone more experienced in these tests give any clarity about what the expected outcome should be (eg. solid colors or not) and can anyone clarify the black line down the middle? Or is it safe to assume that this LCD is not functioning properly?

Comment: The black line is a bad sign. You can try to squeeze the screen at the top of LCD where the line appear, or if you have a chance to open the case you will find wide flexible strips. Try to press/gentle move.  
Not sure about the fading, but for test I would expect to be solid colours straight (no fading).

Comment: The LCD's backside and the electronics/flatcables are all easily accessible for this project since we were still testing. I have already replaced the flatcables, pressed around the edges of the LCD and checked the power supplies. Unfortunately without any improvement in the results

Comment: This is a *repair* question about *undocumented* behavior of a consumer device, there's likely no more progress possible towards resolution within the limited mission of this site, so having it periodically churned back up accomplishes little.

Comment: @RemcoVink How did you trigger the self test? I.e. which wires did you supply voltage to? I'm guessing you have to supply _1)_ the backlight power rails (6+V as per specification) _2)_ the backlight enable pin (3.3V) and _3)_ the BIST pin (3.3V)

Answer (score 1):

Caveat
I have designed (circa '99) integrated micro KOPIN LCD displays to display VGA and VCR signals, yet I have no experience with your monitor, but I recognize the blooming effects.

LCD simple Theory of Operation

We know the pixels are addressed in a matrix of rows and columns with the pixel clock, but the analog characteristics are refreshed as a differential charge voltage at some bias voltage defined as a White (W) level DC Restorer circuit. It switch clamps each signal momentarily during the horizontal blanking interval to this V_w level.

**Each video signal must be AC coupled to do this.  ( Verify) or else DC bias exactly to the differential voltage specs in a range within the Analog voltage.**

The bias level enables a polarized dielectric to hold a charge with low leakage in between the White and Black levels defined by internal voltages. Otherwise leakage currents decay the black to white and covering the screen with fog starting around the edges.  A black signal would look like large pulse signals ||______|| in both polarities. 
 A white signal will look like small pulse near the blanking interval values.|_----------__--- ( not exactly)

When the DC restore circuit stops working or clamps on inverted differential signals ( verify) or puts the applied charge where it causes the overall voltage reference to be wrong, then it starts to bloom around the edges as in your video.

But since you have **not even a ghost of any test patterns** , it may be a simple problem.  Perhaps you can verify the analog signals to be valid then the clocks for pixel clock , V sync, H sync pulses are valid etc or the chip is biased wrong.

[image]